# UIlabel text was not updated in simulator

Tags: view, refresh, uilabel, reload

Here are my code... I've call this initializer from different class. This method should reload my view.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil details:(NSMutableArray *)details {
if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
    // Custom initialization
}


[self.view setNeedsDisplay];


return self;
```

}

And here are my codes in viewdidload method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];




[scrollView setScrollEnabled:TRUE];
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 700)];

MainDeal *deal = [dealData objectAtIndex:0];

if (deal.priceNow != nil)
{
NSString *label = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:deal.priceNow];


    NSLog(@"fir555");
}


lblPrice.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", deal.priceNow];
```

}

In Console, using NSLog,  I can see the text for UILabel has already been changed, but on my simulator, the value for that label is still the same value before initwithnibname method was called.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

remove [self.view setNeedsDisplay]; and try it.

If you don't see text on simulator,retain the **deal** as [deal retain]..